# template<class T, int N> void h(T const(&)[N]); as friend function

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, friend

There is a freestanding function (non-member one) defined as:

```
template<class T, std::size_t N> 
auto foo(T const(&init)[N]) { /* ... */ }
```

foo() is intended to deduce the N (array size)

Additionally, within the same namespace there is a class defined as:

```
class Bar {

friend auto foo( Bar const(&)[/* ??? */] ); /* <-------- The goal to make it right */

private:
    Bar( void ) { /* ... */ }
};
```

**My problem is I am not successful yet to declare the `foo()` as friend to Bar class so that it can access the private members.**

In the `foo()` declaration, there is `std::size_t N` template parameter. But how to make the friendship of all N values?

Many thanks in advance for anyone willing to help.

Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first declaration declares that `foo` is the name of a template. There is no *function* named `foo`. The functions generated from the template named `foo` will have names like `foo<T, N>`, where `T` is a type name and `N` is an integer.

Your friend declaration declares that there should be a `foo` which is the name of a function. That doesn't match up with the `foo` which is the name of a template.

If you want to declare that `Bar` will allow any instantiation of the `foo` template of the form `foo<Bar, *>` to access its privates... well, you can't. You can declare a friend of anything the template generates:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
friend auto foo( T const(&)[N] );
```

You can declare friendship with of a specific template instantiation:

```
friend auto foo<Bar, 20>( Bar const(&)[20] );
```

But you can't declare it a friend of only *some* of the template generated functions. If you tried something like this:

```
template<std::size_t N>
friend auto foo(Bar const(&init)[N]);
```

You would find that your original `foo` wouldn't be able to access it. This is referring to a different template from the `foo` template, as it takes different parameters.